# Conflict between -webkit transform and jQuery .animate()

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit-transform

**Update:
 I setup a fiddle and it seems to work fine - the section that first slides in contains a Google map - I wonder if this is actually the problem...**

I recently added a -webkit-transform card flip to an HTML5 app I working on. This has the unfortunate effect of making a simple carousel that moves horizontally exhibit some strange behavior.

My carousel is structured like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sections">
        <section id="startPage" class="page">
            <div id="card">
                <div class="face front">
                    <p>Some content here</p>
                    <button id="flipFront">A label</button>
                </div>
                <div class="face back">
                    <p>Some content here</p>
                    <button id="flipBack">A label</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery .click() behaviour to cycle through it is this:

`$('#sections').stop().animate({"left": -($('#someDiv').position().left)}, 500);`

This works absolutely fine, until I add the -webkit-transform CSS for the card flip:

```
#startPage {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

#card {
    height: 940px;
    width: 640px; 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color:#000;
}

.rotated{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back, .front {
    height: 940px;
    width: 640px; 
}

.face {position: absolute;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

Now my card flips fine when I use

```
$('#setup, #back').click(function() {
    $('#card').toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

And my carousel still works, but seems to get stuck - e.g. it will slide out partially, and remain stuck in place until I interact with the div in some way, after which it snaps into the correct place.

The problem seem to be

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

When I remove them from the CSS, the carousel works fine, but the flip does not.

I have tested on both Safari and Chrome and the result is the same. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or online demo?

Comment: Not yet - I will set one up though.

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working - the online demo is here: http://www.thaifloodwatch.com/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Only having webkit transform can mess it up, add more information like

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
```

So it is supported by more browsers and you have a fallback.
I have seen this being the issue multiple times, however i cannot guarantee it as i havent tested it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The transform property does not work with animate() function in jquery as the animate() function only accepts values that are numeric in nature. eg. numeric (like "margin:30px").

The transform property takes values which is not numeric.

**Reference:** http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

However you can use a **"step function"** to achieve the transform effect with animate 
or Use the Transit plugin.
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Hope this helps.